# Can the asp.net mvc 4.0 AjaxLogin.js dialog be re-used

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The AjaxLogin.js file is hosting a dialog form which is used in the asp.net mvc 4.0 internet sample to show the Register/Login screen.

Can/Should? this AjaxLogin.js script be reused to show cretae customer/employee etc dialogs?

I tried it and it works, but the file is called Ajax"Login" not Ajax"Customer" whatever.

Should I care for the name "Login" in the filename?